# Dynamically add navigation items in Vue CoreUI

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, core-ui

In my project, I want to add some Ajax loaded menu items to my CoreUI sidebar in Vue. I already found a working solution, but it's kind of hacky and might have timing issues. Therefore I want to ask you, if there is a proper or at least better solution.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60369426/making-coreui-menu-dynamic) from a few days ago, but it doesn't have an answer yet.

```cs
// main.js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    icons,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: {
        App
    },
    data: {
        clientConfiguration: null
    },
    created: async function () {
        let svcResult = await this.$http.get('Picking/ViewerSettings');
        this.clientConfiguration = svcResult.data;
        this.$children[0].$children[0].$children[0].$data.nav[0]._children[0].items =
            svcResult.data.map(vc => ({
                name: vc.name,
                to: 'test/' + vc.name,
                icon: 'cil-spreadsheet'
            }));
    }
})

// _nav.js
export default [
    {
        _name: 'CSidebarNav',
        _children: [
            {
                _name: 'CSidebarNavDropdown',
                name: 'Lists',
                to: '/test',
                icon: 'cil-list-numbered',
                items: []
            },
            // ...
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

The _nav.js file is just an example of data structure that can be rendered by CRenderFunction component [docs](https://coreui.io/vue/docs/components/render-function.html)

The idea behind CRenderFunction is that you can render components from the Array/Object.

In your case, you have two options:

- generate CRenderFunction object on backend,
- generate CRenderFunction object on frontend by computed properties, based on data you got from the backend

Here is the example of the second approach:

in template

```
<CRenderFunction flat :content-to-render="navItems"/>
```

in script:

```
//example array that you receive from backend
const menuItems = [
  { 
    name: 'first item',
    to: '/first',
    icon: 'cil-user'
  },
  { 
    name: 'second item',
    to: '/second'
  },
  { 
    name: 'third item',
    to: '/third'
  }
]

export default {
  computed: {
    navItems () {
      return [
        {
          _name: 'CSidebarNav',
          _children: this.sidebarNavChildren
        }
      ]
    },
    sidebarNavChildren () {
      return menuItems.map(menuItem => {
        return {
          _name: 'CSidebarNavItem',
          name: menuItem.name,
          to: menuItem.to,
          icon: menuItem.icon || 'cil-spreadsheet'
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

navItems computed property result:

```
[{"_name":"CSidebarNav","_children": [
  {"_name":"CSidebarNavItem","name":"first item","to":"/first","icon":"cil-user"}, 
  {"_name":"CSidebarNavItem","name":"second item","to":"/second","icon":"cil-spreadsheet"}, 
  {"_name":"CSidebarNavItem","name":"third item","to":"/third","icon":"cil-spreadsheet"}
 ]
}]
```

Comment: Hi there .. i have same problem.. after your answer i think i understood better, everything seems logical. i have done as you described but nothing happens.. there is no error, but there is no rendered menu as well